# Pandas SystemError: \objects\tupleobject.c:914: bad argument to internal function

Tags: pandas

I am encountering below error message sporadically.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   3827         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
   3828 
-> 3829         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   3830 
   3831     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    428         if is_extension_array_dtype(obj.dtype):
    429             return _unstack_extension_series(obj, level, fill_value)
--> 430         unstacker = _Unstacker(
    431             obj.index, level=level, constructor=obj._constructor_expanddim
    432         )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in __init__(self, index, level, constructor)
    116             raise ValueError("Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow")
    117 
--> 118         self._make_selectors()
    119 
    120     @cache_readonly

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    150 
    151         # make the mask
--> 152         remaining_labels = self.sorted_labels[:-1]
    153         level_sizes = [len(x) for x in new_levels]
    154 

pandas\_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in sorted_labels(self)
    137     @cache_readonly
    138     def sorted_labels(self):
--> 139         indexer, to_sort = self._indexer_and_to_sort
    140         return [line.take(indexer) for line in to_sort]
    141 

pandas\_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _indexer_and_to_sort(self)
    127         sizes = [len(x) for x in levs[:v] + levs[v + 1 :] + [levs[v]]]
    128 
--> 129         comp_index, obs_ids = get_compressed_ids(to_sort, sizes)
    130         ngroups = len(obs_ids)
    131 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py in get_compressed_ids(labels, sizes)
    195     tuple of (comp_ids, obs_group_ids)
    196     """
--> 197     ids = get_group_index(labels, sizes, sort=True, xnull=False)
    198     return compress_group_index(ids, sort=True)
    199 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py in get_group_index(labels, shape, sort, xnull)
    139     labels = map(ensure_int64, labels)
    140     if not xnull:
--> 141         labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(maybe_lift, labels, shape)))
    142 
    143     labels = list(labels)

SystemError: \objects\tupleobject.c:914: bad argument to internal function
```

the above was called from the actual code:

```
   1539                 slice_tmp = my_orderlog.groupby(['ticker','slice']).activeOrderSize.sum().to_frame('size').reset_index()
   1540                 slice_tmp['unit_size'] = slice_tmp['size']/slice_tmp['ticker'].map(wt_map)
   1541                 logger.info(f'TRYING TO DEBUG: {slice_tmp}')
-> 1542                 breakdown = slice_tmp.groupby(['ticker','slice']).unit_size.sum().unstack(level=0)
   1543                 logger.info(f'TRYING TO DEBUG {breakdown}')
```

The SystemError of bad argument of internal functions are not repeatable and very difficult (if impossible) to catch.
Note that I try to log the in-question dataframe "slice_tmp".  but when i get that and run the exact same code, i.e., the "groupby(['ticker','slice']).unit_size.sum().unstack(level=0)" in jupyter notebook, the code runs no problem.

any pointer/ some similar experiences on this odd one please? FWIW i'm running Pandas 1.2.4.